# Read txt File, search for some words and replace them from Hashmap of other words, and preserve the puctuation and uppercase

Tags: java, file, text, io

I have a Hashmap of overused words as a key and their replacement as a value. this some values from the maps.

> [  amazing:astonishing interesting:intriguing literally:frankly
> nice:pleasant hard:taxing change:transform ... ]

I have to implement a class that searches for overused words in a given text file and replaces them with better choices.
**OLD text file** :

> " "Amazing" is really the best way I can think of to describe it.
> Literally, it is hard to express how much I liked it. It was amazingly
> NICE!!!!! Good, not bad. I wouldn't change a bit of it. Please, be
> nice and help me fix my writing!! b BB bbb Bb B."

**NEW text file** :

> " "Astonishing" is really the best way I can think of to describe it.
> Frankly, it is taxing to express how much I liked it. It was amazingly
> PLEASANT!!!!! Superior, not inferior. I wouldn't transform a bit of
> it. Please, be pleasant and help me fix my writing!! cat BB bbb Bb CAT
> "

- TextImprover must preserve the punctuation of the input file.
- Assume all words in the input file are either in all lower case, leading upper case, or all caps.

I have implemented the first function that reads a txt file and makes a map of overused words :

```
public class TextImprover {

    private HashMap<String, String> wordMap ;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param wordMapFileName   name of the file containing the over-used words and their replacements
     */
    public TextImprover(String wordMapFileName) { 
        this.wordMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wordMapFileName));
        String line ;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
            String[] wordLine = line.split("\t");
            //System.out.println(wordLine[1]);
            String overUsedWord = wordLine[0].trim();
            String replaceWord = wordLine[1].trim();
            
            wordMap.put(overUsedWord, replaceWord);
        }
        br.close();
            
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File: "+ wordMapFileName + " not found");   
        }catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I need this Function :

```
/**
     * Replaces all of the over-used words in the given file with better words, based on the word map
     * used to create this TextImprover
     * 
     * @param fileName  name of the file containing the text to be improved
     */
    public void improveText(String fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line ;
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null) {
                String[] lineWords = line.split(" ");
                // The code I'm strugling with 
            }
            br.close();
                
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("File: "+ fileName + " not found");  
            }catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            }

    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the rules for preserving the "upper-/lowercase" state of a word? What if the words have different length? (from your example: what if "NICE" would have been written "NiCe"?) And what is it with the replacement of "B" to "CAT", this was not part of the input replacement map...

Comment: Oh and one more question: shall words be replaced if they are just part of another word, or only complete words?

Comment: - I did not put all the word map, 
- All words in the input file are either in all lower case, leading upper case, or all caps.
- only complete words should be replaced

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? "I need this Function" - does that mean you need someone to correct it or write it for you for free? You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide detailed information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read [ask] and its linked resources

Comment: Thank you @HoRn for your comment, in fact I tried several code but it did not work , I tried to tokenize the line  into words and then search for every word in the list keys and replace it but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `split` method, that also uses a regular expression for splitting, I would use the regular expression (`[a-zA-Z]+`) in the "usual" way to find the next word in your input. (The "usual" way is with a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`.)

Then you would use the `Matcher.replaceAll(Function<MatchResult,String> replacer)` method where you get each match into the function and there you can fetch the replacement from the map and decide if you want to convert it to all upper case or title case (only the first character upper case).

The equivalent of the code you posted (so with out the actual inner replacement stuff, but made easier there) would look like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+"); // best outside the while loop!

// From here replaces your String[] lineWords = line.split(" "); inside the loop
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
String result = matcher.replaceAll(match -> {

    String word = match.group();
    // TODO: find out if word is "ALL CAPS" or "Title Case"
    // TODO: get replacement from map - don't forget to convert the input to the map toLowerCase()
    String replacement = ...;
    return replacement
});

// here your result contains the whole line with all replacements.
```